# jQuery to identify when changing between table rows

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to write a little jQuery to trigger an action when a user leaves an input box within a table, and check if they've moved either to another table, or outside the table.

The issue I'm having is successfully identifying where the focus is. For reasons I won't go into, this project is using **jQuery 1.2.6**, so some of the focus identifying selectors (:focus) don't work.

The trouble is the closest match, **$(document.activeElement)**, only sometimes works, as it often identifies **<body>** as the current active element.

It also appears that the **blur** event fires before the **focus** event, so I can't retrieve it there.

I've set up a working example on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3YgZ/6/

The base of the code is:

```
var currentRow = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var rows = $("table tr");

    // Set ID for each row on init
    rows.each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("id", index);
    });

    // Attach a handler to leaving each input box
    rows.find("input").blur(function() {
        var leavingRow = $(this).parents("tr:first").attr("id");
        var newSelectedRow = $(document.activeElement).parents("tr:first").attr("id");
        if (newSelectedRow != null && leavingRow != newSelectedRow) {
            alert("row changed");
        }
    });

});
```

How can I determine the current focus element in jQuery 1.2.6?

Comment: have you tried time travel to 2007? is this JSF's fault?

Comment: none of the rows have ids in your example code

Comment: explain some more why you cant use the focus event? i dont understand why your code cant go into the focus event?

Comment: @Overflew I can provide much simpler option to this **without using `.focus` hack** and you can still keep the previous and new row id of the inputbox on click you keen? :) ANd not sure why you are using 1.2.6 ask your Team lead or tech lead to reconsider this :) here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/szCuA/ and let me know if this helps will set it as answer and prettify it. cheers

Comment: **or this http://jsfiddle.net/szCuA/1/ hope this helps your purpose.